# Formatting text file in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to format an existing text file, the contents of text file are:

> Aurangabad
>
> Adilabad
>
> Beed

I want to format it like:

> Aurangabad|Aurangabad,
>
> Adilabad|Adilabad,
>
> Beed|Beed,

I am not so good in Python file handling.

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: Would you give this a try and let us know where you get stuck? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code to do so:

```
with open('file_name.txt','r') as file:
    list_of_lines = file.readlines()

new_lines_list = []
for line in list_of_lines:
    line = line.replace('\n','')   #because each line end with this and we don't need it now (\n is the newline chr)
    new_lines_list.append('{0}|{0}\n'.format(line)) #the same as - new_lines_list.append(line+'|'+line+'\n')

with open('file_name.txt','w') as file:
    string_to_write = ''.join(new_lines_list)
    file.write(string_to_write)
```

if you don't understand the with statement: it is basically to open the file and at the end it will close itself (and even if some exception occur it will still close (I explain bad if you don't understand go [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm))